# Alternatives to "to build on an idea"?

Tags: phrase-request, phrases, synonyms

I'm looking for an different way to express a sentence such as:

> **I build on** the fact that human beings are equal.

The [synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/build%20on) I found don't correspond with the meaning of starting from a concept, stating a postulate.  I'm putting forward a philosophical assumption, a basis for further argumentation.

Comment: @Probably : Why do you feel you need a different way to express that sentence?  There's nothing outwardly wrong with it, so what would you like to convey instead?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what it is you are going to be saying, so it is a little difficult to know what phrase would serve your purposes the best, but the following substitutions for "I build on" should give you a decent range to choose from

- Further to my argument that...
- Based upon the assumption that...
- I
  supplement the presupposition that...
- I extend the discourse relating
  to the fact that...

These all relate to the idea that there is an idea that you are building on.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- "my starting point is the fact that all human beings are equal"
- "the foundation (of my belief) is the fact that all human beings are equal"
- "my baseline is the fact that all human beings are equal"